# Convert string to Json in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, javascriptserializer

I want to convert string to json, but all I get is null or error

For example I want to convert this string:

```
string json =
                "{\"$id\":\"1\",\"Result\":{\"$id\":\"2\",\"ListRate\":[{\"$id\":\"3\",\"Title\":\"fetures\",\"ShoppingRateId\":3,\"Rate\":0.0},{\"$id\":\"4\",\"Title\":\"Graphic\",\"ShoppingRateId\":2,\"Rate\":0.0},{\"$id\":\"5\",\"Title\":\"worth of price\",\"ShoppingRateId\":1,\"Rate\":0.0}],\"MyRate\":[{\"$id\":\"6\",\"Title\":\"worth of price\",\"ShoppingRateId\":1,\"Rate\":1.5},{\"$id\":\"7\",\"Title\":\"Graphic\",\"ShoppingRateId\":2,\"Rate\":2.0},{\"$id\":\"8\",\"Title\":\"fetures\",\"ShoppingRateId\":3,\"Rate\":2.0}],\"ListRated\":[{\"$id\":\"9\",\"Title\":\"worth of price\",\"ShoppingRateId\":1,\"Rate\":30.0,\"theCount\":1,\"theSum\":1.5},{\"$id\":\"10\",\"Title\":\"Graphic\",\"ShoppingRateId\":2,\"Rate\":40.0,\"theCount\":1,\"theSum\":2.0},{\"$id\":\"11\",\"Title\":\"fetures\",\"ShoppingRateId\":3,\"Rate\":40.0,\"theCount\":1,\"theSum\":2.0}]},\"StatusCode\":\"Created\",\"Description\":null}";
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var myclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductDto>(json);
```

And Class of product:

```
public class RootObject
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public ProductDto Result { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public object Description { get; set; }
}

 public class ProductDto
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<MyRateDto> ListRate { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<MyRateDto> MyRate { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<ShoppingRateDto> ListRated { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShoppingRateDto
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public long ShoppingRateId { get; set; }

        public double Rate { get; set; }

        public int theCount { get; set; }

        public double theSum { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyRateDto
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public long ShoppingRateId { get; set; }

        public double Rate { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm a bit confused how should I convert it .
Also I have using "RootObject" instead of "ProductDto", but nothing changed ...

Some of error:

> Additional information: The best overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Additional information: Cannot create and populate list type
>   System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Site.Model.MyRateDto]. Path 'Result.ListRate'

Comment: Why not serialize the ProductDto so you know the json string you need to do the desexualization?

Comment: You mentioned an exception, what exception? It might be helpful to see that with the question.

Comment: @Fran so how do you think ?

Comment: @neouser99 I have added some new information

Comment: Seems like the error is a decent hint. Instead of using IQueryable (basically any interface collections), try using a concrete collection. e.g. `List<T>`

Comment: @neouser99 yes, I have changing IQueryable  to List and it solved , write it on  answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the error is a decent hint. Instead of using `IQueryable` (basically any interface collections), try using a concrete collection. e.g. `List<T>`

Serializers have to work with concrete classes to be able to instantiate them through reflection. When they are reading class definitions, and they come across interfaces, seldom can the serializer make a choice on the correct implementation. Since there are potentially many many concrete instances of different collection interfaces, you should provide the serializers with concrete types in order to work properly.